# Testing a Spring system with several REQUIRES_NEW methods

Tags: database, spring, testing

I'm writing tests for a system with several methods that are annotated with REQUIRES_NEW. How can I write the test and do automatic clean up? Currently, I have to manually clean up since there're several transactions which have committed before the test ends.

Is there any library for taking a snapshot of the database before the test and apply that snapshot after the test?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please include your test code and the code you test. What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi, I'm not encountering errors, just difficulties. Several methods use REQUIRES_NEW, which will create another transaction and commit separately. Those changes are not rolled back in the test. So I'd like to know if there is any elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [spring TestContext framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing)

the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test

--edit--

I haven't found a solution yet, perhaps it is what **PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW** intend for: to start a completely independent transaction and can commit or rollback independently with the outer transaction.

A possible workaround might be to re-populate the database between tests in @BeforeTransaction and @AfterTransaction

There is a [open ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6908) for your reference

--edit--

Taking snapshots of db is quite complicated and depends on the underlying db. I haven't found a ready-made library or tool to satisfy your needs. even if there is any, it might be too heavy to use it only for test purpose.

spring provides [Embedded database support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support), but it is limited to embedded db like h2 and every time it create a entirely new db and destroy it after test

so, I guess you have to go with restoring the tables/rows updated during the test by your own.

Comment: Hi, it can't rollback since several methods use REQUIRES_NEW, which will create another transaction and commit separately. Those changes are not rolled back.

Comment: Septem, do you know any library that can take a snapshot of the DB and re-populate it later?